# Prometheus Timer Callback

Tags: java, prometheus

I'm currently switching our Java backend from **DropWizard** to **Prometheus** and I'm having trouble finding a good substitute for DropWizards Timer while instrumenting a library which has a metrics callback looking like this:

```
new ImageUploader(
        new MetricsCallback() {
            @Override
            public void timer(long aLong) {
                new MetricRegistry()
               .timer("outbound.image-upload.timer")
               .update(aLong, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        });
```

Prometheus' DropWizard-adapter uses **Histogram.Timer** as substitute, but there is no way of setting/updating the timer manually.

Is there a way to do this in Prometheus, or do I have to wrap every call to this libray into `startTimer()` + `observeDuration()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already defined your metric uploadLatency as a static class field as usual and `aLong` is in milliseconds, you want:

```
uploadLatency.observe(aLong / 1000.0)
```

Comment: Apparently I'm blind. Thanks Brian!